# SQL Filtering on multiple properties

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Database with a table Books:

| Id | IsVisible | Slug | UserId | Name | CreationDate | Description | IsAdult | BirthDate | City | Siren |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | julien | 56D1C3BE-7674-4CF0-6940-08D9D09EC5A8 | Julien | 2022-01-05 22:57:39.2341686 | Ici c'est le book de Julien | 0 | 1981-08-02 00:00:00.0000000 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | sophie | 123F9FC7-B638-4681-6941-08D9D09EC5A8 | Sophie | 2022-01-05 22:57:39.2346909 | Ici c'est le book de Sophie | 0 | 1984-12-03 00:00:00.0000000 | NULL | NULL |

And a table BookProperties which contains a lict of properties about books:

| ObjectId | ObjectType | ObjectPropertyTypeId | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | BookType | Photographer |
| 1 | 1 | Gender | M |
| 1 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | ArtisticNude |
| 1 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | Beauty |
| 1 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | Erotic |
| 1 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | Fashion |
| 1 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | Lingerie |
| 1 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | Portraits |
| 1 | 1 | Work | ExteriorPhoto |
| 1 | 1 | Work | FashionShow |
| 1 | 1 | Work | StudioPhoto |
| 2 | 1 | BookType | Model |
| 2 | 1 | Gender | F |
| 2 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | Beauty |
| 2 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | Fashion |
| 2 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | Lingerie |
| 2 | 1 | TypeOfPhotos | Portraits |

I want to filter books by properties using checkboxes on a filter page.
Filter query is generated by the user interactions like this example:

```sql
SELECT
DISTINCT BOOK.NAME,
BOOK.ISADULT,
CONCAT('http://',BOOK.SLUG,'.foo.com') AS LINK,
VISUAL.TITLE,
VISUAL.DESCRIPTION,
ITEMS.WIDTH,
ITEMS.HEIGHT,
ITEMS.FILENAME
FROM BOOKS AS BOOK
INNER JOIN BOOKPROPERTIES AS PROPERTIES ON BOOK.ID=PROPERTIES.OBJECTID AND PROPERTIES.OBJECTTYPE=1
INNER JOIN VISUALS AS VISUAL ON BOOK.ID= VISUAL.BOOKID AND VISUAL.ISTHUMBNAIL=CAST(1 AS BIT) AND VISUAL.GALERYID IS NULL
LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM VISUALITEMS AS ITEM WHERE ITEM.FORMAT= 6) AS ITEMS ON VISUAL.ID = ITEMS.VISUALID
WHERE PROPERTIES.OBJECTTYPE=1
AND BOOK.ID IN (
SELECT OBJECTID FROM BOOKPROPERTIES WHERE OBJECTPROPERTYTYPEID='Gender' AND VALUE IN ('F','M')
and ObjectId in (SELECT OBJECTID FROM BOOKPROPERTIES WHERE OBJECTPROPERTYTYPEID='BookType' AND VALUE IN ('Model','Photographer','MakeUp')))
```

each new category of filter selected add a nested query like this:

```sql
SELECT OBJECTID FROM BOOKPROPERTIES WHERE OBJECTPROPERTYTYPEID='{PropertyType}' AND VALUE IN ('{Value1}','{Value2}','{Value3}')
```

Execution plan is available here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1eqMaH3t

It does the job, but I'm sure there is a more efficient way to achieve that.
Is someone have a better idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a SQL Fiddle of the above? Can you use paste the execution plan using (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/#:~:text=How%20to%20Use%20Paste%20the%20Plan.%20Step%201%3A,and%20click%20View%20XML.%20Copy%20all%20of%20that.)

Comment: Here is the link for the execution plan.
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1eqMaH3t

Thanks for the link, it's an amazing tool.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the link to the plan?

Comment: Hello, Julien. Please, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question.